# Append word from editText to textview when i click on button? Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, textview, android-button

I have problem, when i want to append my TextView with new word from editText it's doesnt work.
I know why but i can't find the solution. 
The problem is from the button every time i press it to add new word, it will reset the string which save the word.

So how i can save my string with old word?

````java
Valide_mots.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int i = 0;
                String[] liste_mots = new String[100];
                String mot =  Saisie_mots.getText().toString();
                liste_mots[i] = mot;
                Affichage_mots.setText(liste_mots[i]);
                i++;
            }
        });```

Thx for all :)
````

Comment: You create the array every time the button is clicked. I am confused about your confusion

Comment: I know when the button is click the  array is recreate

Comment: So how would the old word still be there? you need to create it only once. And not set i back to 0 every time, so it doesn't write the new word in the same index 0. And also your set text is not appending, just changing